# utf_encode letters è ò àùì php

Tags: php, utf-8, non-ascii-characters

I have a problem with PHP.
I have a form with input named text.
If I send a word with accenture letters like "coupè", the `$_POST['text']` return me "coupÃƒÂ¨" also `utf8_encode($text)`.

How is possible? The Db is utf-8 bin.

Comment: That looks like valid UTF-8, only you are looking at it with something which isn't properly configured for UTF-8.  Maybe your terminal is Latin-1?

Comment: If you are looking for *coupé*  that's spelled with a grave accent, not acute.

Comment: no it's all for UTF-8, I don't understand why happen

Comment: Correction, it's double-encoded.  The (pseudo-)word **coupè** is `coupÃ¨` in Latin-1, and if you recode that from Latin-1 to UTF-8 a second time, you get `coupÃÂ¨`.  Still the `ƒ` is unaccounted for.